# Is there any central world organization which authenticate achievement of various space agencies missions?

Tags: mars, future-missions, isro, mars-orbiter-mission

Recently Isro's mars orbitor has completed 4 years in mars orbit I guess. I am proud of that as I am Indian. but as curious person I still wonder 
for proofs of that mars orbitor is still in mars orbit . Isro still havenot possesed capabilities like nasa to produce good images , so its hard a 
bit for common people like me to believe in that. I am not questioning credibilities of ISRO. Before few years same questiones were raised for NASA moon mission.
So big questions is that is there any oraganization which take care of whether achievement of missions are authenticate or not ?

Comment: There will always be people who 'don't belive in science' or accomplishments and proving these people wrong is virtually impossible as they're dead-set in their ways. If you're looking for proof that the MOM mission is still active, you can check the Wikipedia page which cites all of the orbiter's activity.

Comment: Does it really have to be a central world organization or does the existence of various other trustworthy organizations which validate the authenticity of some space missions count?

Comment: If you don't trust space and science agencies around the world and are still looking for a record keeping association, the closest I could find was a record in the 'Guinness World Records' under 'Most active spacecraft orbiting another planet' which cites the MOM mission as active.

Comment: Furious people didnt understand what I was asking

Comment: People perfectly understood what you were asking, they just questioned the need for such a *central world organization*.

Comment: if they understood perfectly then why they haven't came with answer like below one !

Comment: One way of verifying that a spacecraft is still operating is to listen for telemetry from it.  OK, you'd need a lot of expensive, specialist infrastructure to do it, but the signals are out there and available to be recieved if you have the right equipment.  In 1966 the Soviet Union made the first soft landing on the moon but Jodrell Bank in the UK broke the news and published the first ever photo from the surface much to the annoyance of the Soviets http://www.jodrellbank.net/the-luna-9-space-hack-4th-feb-1966/

Comment: @RahulRabhadiya Because minus the section about the FAI, the answer below is "No". We wanted to make sure that you had written the question in such a way that you would get the most informative answer.

Comment: @called2voyage how about  jodrellbank.net/the-luna-9-space-hack-4th-feb-1966 ?? Look you can minus the answer , you can question my question but you cant question in my belief system. I always believe that science is the only way to understand truth.But you can not ignore accountability and credibility . So I was curious & I asked.

Comment: @RahulRabhadiya I didn't say there was no accountability. You were asking specifically for a centralized organization serving a broad purpose--there is no such organization. However, as you have pointed out, there are organizations that do provide independent verification, and that's all I was asking.

Comment: The Deep Space Network supports ISRO when the spacecraft is not visible from India. If you keep checking their website you might be able to see when the spacecraft is using the network.That probably won't convince your typical conspiracy theorist but it is a verification of sorts. Here is the site: https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Some spaceflight records are authenticated by the [FAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9d%C3%A9ration_A%C3%A9ronautique_Internationale) (Fédération Aéronautique Internationale) under its sub-body FAI Astronautic Records Commission but these are generally highest/longest/fastest type records involving human spaceflight. A [famous controversy](https://airandspace.si.edu/stories/editorial/why-yuri-gagarin-remains-first-man-space-even-though-he-did-not-land-inside-his) arose over Yuri Gagarin's flight because of FAI rules stating that the pilot had to land in his vehicle to be eligible for a record.

But the general facts of space accomplishments are typically announced by the agency that performs them, and it is up to everyone who doubts them to use their critical thinking and research skills to confirm or deny them for their own purposes.

Comment: Thanks , "it is up to everyone who doubts them to use their critical thinking and research skills to confirm or deny them for their own purposes." its pretty good line ! but to be critical is wrong or right ?

Comment: @RahulRabhadiya critical thinking and criticizing are different things